# SAML SSO how does it work?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

Let's say we have a service provider app called A hosted on tomcat, a user clicks a link to the SP A. SP A sees no token is provided so it redirects the user to the IdP for authentication (with a SAML Authn request provided by some means). The IdP then redirects the user to some common login page where credentials are provided, assuming that these credentials are correct the IdP creates a SAML response with a token and some assertions about the subject, and sends it back to SP A. SP A sees this and allows the user access into the application. Great!

I have a few questions though

1. How is the authorisation request/response sent, I understand there is a redirect binding and a POST binding where the SAMLResponse and request are encoded either as a query param, or sent as an XHTML form in case of a POST binding. But I'm not sure which is used where?
2. A service provider is the thing providing a service, so Office 365 or Sales force for example. Is each one a separate service provider? I ask as I watched a video where the guy said the service provider was the thing that hosted these services, so I'm not sure of the correct answer here?
3. How is the token stored on the client side? So for example I am now authenticated against SP A, the user then tries to use SP B from the same machine/browser window, how does SP B and the IdP know that the user has already authenticated and therefore doesn't need to re-authenticate. I.e. the SSO aspect of it.
4. Does SP B need to be hosted on the same tomcat instance for this to work?

Answer (score 3):

I dedicated significant time to get SSO working for me. The most helpful document was [this specification](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf)

The answers below are based on this experience:

1. Redirect or Post binding is used depending on a respective HTTP request header. The Post binding is recommended since it does not imply restrictions on data volume transferred.
2. A Service Provider in this context is anything that clients request. There may be many of them, participating in the same SSO scheme.
3. The service providers must be SSO-aware, which includes handling of the authentication response data. Usually you don't have to implement the protocol - there are ready-made frameworks that your SP can utilize.
4. Service Providers may reside on different servers.

Answer (score 2):

From my own experience:

1. You choose your own SAMLBinding (redirect or post) depending on what your idp and sp supports. This binding type will be used both for the 1st step (SP -> Idp) and 2nd step (IdP -> SP). If you have some running environment, open your browser devtools and look at network tab to see what happens. It's just a way to send data from browser to SP/IdP.
2. Both Office 365 and Salesforce.com are cloud services, right? Let's take Office 365. it means that beyond "end-user" services (like Word, Excel) there is some technical SSO service which are common to the platform. It can be viewed as lower (or technical) service layers, I think that what you speaker meant.
3. The SAML token is stored by you SP application inside your browser, either hidden inside web page, cookie or web storage. It depends on how your SP is implemented.

SAML response can be validate by each SP based on shared private key, so it will decrypt the token using this key and be able to grant user without the help of IdP redirection.

4. Tomcat have some extension to support SAML. But SAML is designed to work without being on the same instance, as the opposite as basic JSESSIONID cookies.
   So you have several instances, of course.